# Problema acentuação PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou com uma dúvida referente a acentuação, especificamente o retorno de `Ç`. Meu banco está com o *collation* `latin1_swedish_ci`, estou usando as tags HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 <html lang="pt-BR">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

E no banco fica registrado corretamente o `Ç` e acentos, conforme abaixo:

[image]

Mas na hora de exibir os dados, aparece dessa forma:

[image]

O PHP exibe dessa forma (na 3ª linha fiz um teste que não deu certo):

```
foreach ($saidas as $saida) { ?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $saida['reserva'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $saida['motorista'] ?></td>
   <td><?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", true); echo $saida['setor'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $saida['email'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $saida['veiculo'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $saida['destino'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $saida['data'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $saida['saida'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $saida['retorno'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $saida['retorno_real'] ?></td>
   </tr>

<?
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: faça o teste com a collation para `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Rafael, alterei a collation do banco e das tabelas mas não deu certo também.

Comment: @Diego você está usando algum framework ou esta com PHP puro? e lembre-se, quando voce fizer as mudanças na collation os dados que já estao no banco não sofreram alteração, apenas os novos dados serao validados com a nova regra.

Comment: Pois é Diego.. Você encontrará dezenas de dicas diferentes e tentará todas. A maioria sem sucesso e sem saber o que está fazendo. E ainda correndo risco de corromper os dados. 
O correto a se fazer é começar com diagnósticos e procurar entender como analisar a situação atual do ambiente. Nunca aplique um remédio sem fazer um diagnóstico adequado. Não espere uma solução mágica porque não tem. Mas se quiser, pode continuar tentando a sorte. Logo logo alguém vai te indicar o `utf8_decode()` a esmo. É aí que a mágica começa a acontecer. rsrsrs

Comment: Esta pergunta foi tópico deste debate: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4640/132

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

```
<td><?php echo utf8_decode($saida['setor']) ?></td>
```

Comment: Certo, mais isso são para itens que vem do banco ou vale para qualquer palavra com carácter especial?

Comment: @JulioCesardaSilvaBarros Isso vale para saidas do banco. Para o HTML em si, no cabeçalho tem que declarar:         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

Comment: Certo, você pode analisar minha questão?
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132100/problemas-com-utf-8-em-projeto-php
já tentei declarando dessa forma.

Answer (score 2):

Caso esteja conectando-se ao MySQL via terminal (Com o famoso comando mysql -u nomedousario -p), tenha certeza que esta conexão também está com o character-set correto.

Acontece que muitas vezes (isso aconteceu comigo) a sua conexão do PHP com o MySQL pode estar perfeita, tudo com o mesmo encoding, character set e collation, tudo perfeito. Mas quando você confere pelo terminal vê os caracteres quebrados.

Sim, dá a impressão de que o PHP e o MySQL estão errados e o terminal está certo, mas não necessariamente.

Para fazer o teste, conecte-se ao MySQL pelo terminal com o seginte comando: **mysql -u nomeusuario -p --default-character-set=charset**

Onde: nomeusuario é o seu nome de usuário e charset é o charset que você está querendo configurar o servidor.

Vamos supor que seu usuário seja root você deixou PHP, HTML e MYSQL configurados para rodar em UTF-8. Sua conexão deve ficar algo assim:

```
mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8
Ou então para o famoso: ISO-8859-1
```

mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=latin1
Caso a sua conexão ocorra com o seu charset desejado e os dados ficaram estragados, então significa que ali eles foram inseridos por outro charset. Ahá! Pegamos o erro!

Então se você alterar na unha (via update) os dados (Agora sua coenxão está no charset certo) vão ficar corretos no terminal.
Se tudo ocorreu certo ao atualizar sua página PHP você notará que os caracteres também ficaram certos lá.

Para definir o default-character-set no MYSQL para não precisar ficar forçando via terminal basta especificá-lo no seu arquivo de configuração do MySQL (my.cnf ou my.ini).

```
 [mysql]
  default-character-set=seucharset
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração do charset para utf-8 mas ainda assim não consigo exibir corretamente o Ç

Comment: é xarope mesmo, relaxa que isso sempre da encrenca.
veja esse link http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/443220-resolvidoproblemas-de-acentuacao-php-mysql/