# Problemas com UTF-8 em projeto PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou aprendendo PHP e estou enfrentando alguns problemas com os caracteres especiais, vejam:

[image: Veja circulado em vermelho]

o engraçado é que nos itens da tabela exibe a acentuação e os caracteres especiais. 
E sim, já tentei usar as definições `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`

e também 
`<?php ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');?>`

até os `<meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`

e 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

mais ainda persiste o problema.

Este é meu formulário principal:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?phpini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');?>
        <title>Gerenciação de Tarefas</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h2>Gerenciador de Tarefas</h2>

        <?php include('formulario.php'); ?>
        <?php if ($exibir_tabela) : ?>
            <?php include('tabela.php'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Este é o formulário de cadastro:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><b>Nova tarefa</b></legend>
        <?php 
            $_id = $tarefa["id"];
            $_nome = $tarefa["nome"];
            $_descricao = $tarefa["descricao"];
            $_prioridade = $tarefa["prioridade"];
            $_prazo = $tarefa["prazo"];
            $_concluida = $tarefa["concluida"];
        ?>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "id"
            value = "<?php echo $_id; ?>" />

        <label>
            Tarefa
            <br>
            <input type = "text" name = "nome" 
                value = "<?php echo $_nome; ?>"/>
        </label>
        <br><br>

        <label>
            Descrição(Opcional)
            <br>
            <textarea name = "descricao"><?php echo $_descricao; ?></textarea> 
        </label>
        <br><br>

        <label>
            Prazo(Opcional)
            <br>
            <input type = "text" name = "prazo"
                value = "<?php echo traduz_data_para_view($_prazo); ?>"/>
        </label>
        <br><br>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Prioridade</legend>
            <label>
                <input type = "radio" name = "prioridade" value = "1"<?php echo ($_prioridade == 1)?'checked':''; ?>/>
                Baixa

                <input type = "radio" name = "prioridade" value = "2" <?php echo ($_prioridade == 2)?'checked':''; ?>/>
                Média

                <input type = "radio" name = "prioridade" value = "3"<?php echo ($_prioridade == 3)?'checked':''; ?>/>
                Alta
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <br><br>

        <label>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "concluida" value = "1" <?php echo ($_concluida == 1)?'checked':''; ?>/>
            Tarefa Concluída
        </label>
        <br><br>

        <input type = "submit" value = "<?php echo ($tarefa["id"] > 0) ? "Atualizar" : "Cadastrar"; ?>"/> 
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Este é o formulário da tabela:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <table border = 1>
            <tr>
                <th>Tarefas</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>  
                <th>Prazo</th>
                <th>Prioridade</th>
                <th>Concluída</th>
                <th>Opções</th>
            </tr>

            <?php if($lista_tarefas != null){
            foreach ($lista_tarefas as $tarefa) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $tarefa["nome"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $tarefa["descricao"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo traduz_data_para_view($tarefa["prazo"]); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo traduz_prioridade($tarefa["prioridade"]); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo traduz_concluida($tarefa["concluida"]); ?></td>
                    <td> 
                        <a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $tarefa["id"];?>">
                        Editar
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; 
            };?>

        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Isso começou quando em separei o formulário para melhor manutenção, os 3 formulários estão ai em cima!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40706/discussion-between-julio-cesar-da-silva-barros-and-lvcs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evitar problemas com caracteres especiais você precisa assegurar que todas as vertentes do seu projeto usem o mesmo charset.

- Definir a tag meta no HTML para utf-8
- Definir o charset para utf-8 no PHP (via header ou set)
- Todos os seus arquivos .html, .php, devem utilizar **encoding UTF-8 sem bom (utf-8 without BOM)**.
- Definir a sua conexão/transmissão de dados entre aplicação e DB para o mesmo charset.

**Pelas respostas e comentários acima, as 2 primeira você já fez, faça o restante que vai funcionar.**

> Alterar charset da conexão:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conexao,"utf8");
```

> Alterar Encoding dos Arquivos (Notepad++):

[image: Alterar encoding notepad]

E te ajude, procure uma IDE e não um bloco de notas melhorzin.... vai facilitar aprendizado/trabalho.

Comment: Era isso mesmo cara, valeu mesmo, procurei pra caramba essa resposta!
Vou utilizar o dreamweaver a partir de agora!

Comment: @JulioCesardaSilvaBarros praticamente a mesma coisa daqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43193/d%c3%bavida-com-charset-iso-8859-1-e-utf8

Answer (score 0):

Antes de escrever qualquer saída em HTML, tente o comando abaixo:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Também é importante checar o charset do editor (ou editores) que você está utilizando.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Valeu cara, conferi aqui e deixei do jeito que ti disse!